# Overalignment of an existing type in c++17

Tags: c++, c++17

Given an existing type `T`, it is possible to overalign it on the stack with the `alignas()` keyword:

```
  alignas(1024) T variable;
```

For dynamic allocation, we have a cumbersome syntax :

```
  T *variable = new (std::align_val_t(1024)) T;
```

However, there are two problems with this syntax:

1. Microsoft's compiler emits error [C2956](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2956?view=msvc-150) although the syntax is valid;
2. There seems to be no corresponding operator for destruction and aligned delete.

A workaround seems would be the definition of a new type that encapsulates `T`:

```
alignas(1024)
struct AlignedType {
  T _;
};

Alignedtype variable = new AlignedType;  // Properly aligned in c++17
delete variable;                         // Suitable aligned deallocation function called in c++17
```

This workaround is messy, if `T`'s constructor has parameters, we must add some syntaxic shenanigan to forward constructor arguments, and we need to access `variable._` to get the real content.

Inheritance is a bit simpler, but if `T` is a fundamental type (like `uint32_t`), we can't use inheritance.

**My question** is as follow:

Does something like

```
using AlignedType = alignas(32) T;
```

is possible (the above does not compile) or is it just not possible to dynamically allocate an *existing* type using custom alignment without resorting to syntaxic complexities ?

Comment: Why would there be an aligned delete operator? The object has to be aligned the same way it was aligned when it was allocated.

Comment: @user253751, one possible implementation for an aligned allocation function is to allocate the requeted bytes plus the requested alignement and return a pointer which has been aligned correctly. To deallocate, the deallocation function must find the original pointer before alignment. One can imagine that the standard allocation function does not store that kind of information hence it would not be possible to mix a standard new with an aligned delete or vice-versa.

Comment: @user253751 There seems to be an "overaligned" `operator delete`, see the overload (3) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete, or the one mentioned in the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/support.dynamic#new.delete.single-11.sentence-2.

Comment: It's because if a constructor fails (IIRC) the delete operator matching `new` is called. Otherwise the generic delete operator is called. It does seem a bit silly.

Comment: @user253751 @user253751 And, does it make sense to call different versions of `operator new` in these two cases? Check [new.delete.single/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.dynamic#new.delete.single-11). Doesn't it imply that allocation with `operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)` needs to be deallocated by `operator delete(void*, std::align_val_t)`? Instead of by `operator delete(void* ptr)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve the equivalent of your hypothetical:

```
using AlignedType = alignas(32) T;
```

There is no such thing as a type that is equivalent to another type but with different alignment. If the language allowed something like that to exist, imagine all the extra overload resolution rules we would have to add to the language.

The syntax

```
new (std::align_val_t(1024)) T;
```

should work. However, MSVC has a bug where it considers `::operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)` to be a "placement allocation function" rather than a "usual allocation function". This leads to the error you are seeing, where it complains that a placement allocation function matches a usual deallocation function.

(It seems that it is the standard's fault for not being clear: [CWG2592](https://wg21.link/cwg2592). However, MSVC is to blame too; why did they choose to interpret the standard in a way that makes `new (std::align_val_t(x)) T` illegal?)

A workaround is to implement your own `operator new` and matching `operator delete` that delegate to the ones that you actually want to call:

```
struct alignment_tag {};

void* operator new(std::size_t size, alignment_tag, std::align_val_t alignment) {
    return operator new(size, alignment);
}

void operator delete(void* p, alignment_tag, std::align_val_t alignment) {
    operator delete(p, alignment);
}
```

Now you can do

```
T *variable = new (alignment_tag{}, std::align_val_t(1024)) T;
```

I personally would wrap this in something like:

```
template <class T>
struct AlignedDeleter {
    AlignedDeleter(std::align_val_t alignment) : alignment_(alignment) {}
    void operator()(T* ptr) const {
        ptr->~T();
        ::operator delete(ptr, alignment_);
    }
    std::align_val_t alignment_;
};

template <typename T>
using AlignedUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T, AlignedDeleter<T>>;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
AlignedUniquePtr<T> make_unique_aligned(std::align_val_t alignment, Args&&... args) {
    return AlignedUniquePtr<T>(new (alignment_tag{}, alignment) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), AlignedDeleter<T>(alignment));
}
```

(You can always call `.release()` if you need to.)

Comment: You write that `new (std::align_val_t(1024)) T;` should work. But isn't there then a problem with `delete`? In particular, it will call `operator delete(void* ptr)`, but shouldn't `operator delete(void*, std::align_val_t)` be called instead (which is called by `new` expression in case of exception)? Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/dseaYxrTv.

Comment: My point is that when the `delete` expression is resolved, there is generally no knowledge about the alignment placement parameter provided to the `new` expression (possibly in a different TU). This holds for any compiler, not just MSVC.

Comment: Nice syntax, however, you eluded how to call the destroy+deallocate delete operator. If I understand correctly, your `std::unique_ptr<T>` is incorrect, it will not call the correct delete.

Comment: @Étienne @DanielLangr It is not required to call `operator delete(void*, std::align_val_t)` in order to deallocate memory that was allocated using `operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)`. The plain `operator delete(void*)` will do just fine.

Comment: @BrianBi, you can't. Using plain `delete` with the aligned new results in heap corruption on MSVC. The aligned new calls [_aligned_malloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=msvc-150) but standard `delete` does not call [_aligned_free](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-free?view=msvc-150)

Comment: @BrianBi I am not a language lawyer, but it seems to me that http://eel.is/c++draft/support.dynamic#new.delete.single-11 implies the opposite.

Comment: ok, I was wrong. I'll update the answer

Comment: The answer to the original question is "it's not possible". However, I like your syntax. It can be simplified to  `enum class alignment_t : size_t {};` and then `void *operator new(size_t size, alignment_t alignment) { return ::operator new(size, std::align_val_t(alignment)); }`.